# Error to install MYSQLCLIENT python Linux

Tags: python, mysql, linux

Im trying to install the mysqlclient on linux, and keeping reciving this error  bellow.

I already tried update the:

sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

And the error persit:

```
^C(venv) pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.2.tar.gz (88 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/felipecid/PycharmProjects/djangoAgenda/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ct6grj28/mysqlclient_e1f80e76b30f4edaaa24bdcfc6a54e18/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ct6grj28/mysqlclient_e1f80e76b30f4edaaa24bdcfc6a54e18/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-1wsevah8
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ct6grj28/mysqlclient_e1f80e76b30f4edaaa24bdcfc6a54e18/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: comando não encontrado
    /bin/sh: mariadb_config: comando não encontrado
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: comando não encontrado
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ct6grj28/mysqlclient_e1f80e76b30f4edaaa24bdcfc6a54e18/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ct6grj28/mysqlclient_e1f80e76b30f4edaaa24bdcfc6a54e18/setup_posix.py", line 65, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ct6grj28/mysqlclient_e1f80e76b30f4edaaa24bdcfc6a54e18/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
        raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please do not post text output as images or links to images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: Sorry now is better

Comment: `/bin/sh: mysql_config: comando não encontrado` Is MySQL installed?

Comment: try `pip install mysqlclient==2.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is beacause im using the DISTR Linux Mint Version, just sawp for a regular Unbuntu version and works!